# Solve the K_ELEMENT problem using INTERSECT

Tags: time-complexity, polynomial-time-reductions

Suppose you have a machine that takes inputs a set of sets, $\{S_1,S_2,\dots S_n\}$, and an integer $k$.  The machine then returns `True` if $S_1$ intersects every other set $S_2,\dots,S_n$ in at least one place and otherwise returns `False`.  Call this problem the INTERSECT problem.  Now call the K_ELEMENT problem the problem of deciding whether $S_1$ intersects every other set in at least $k$ places.  Give a polynomial time reduction of K_ELEMENT to INTERSECT.

---

I think I know how to give a non-polynomial time reduction.  For a given instance $\{S_1,\dots,S_n\}$ and $k$ of the K_ELEMENT problem, we can compute every subset of $S_i$ of size $|S_i|-k+1$ and give $S_1$ together with all of these constructed sets as inputs to the INTERSECT solver.  The problem is that as $|S_i|=n_i$ and $k$ grow, the number of subsets this has to generate grows like $\binom{n_i}k$ which is not polynomial.

---

So how to do this while generating fewer sets?  Suppose for simplicity that you just take two sets $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $T$ any set, and $k=2$.  Then we want to know whether some $k$ elements of $T$ are elements of $S$, and we can only do this by making a single call to INTERSECT then ... I just can't see a way of making subsets to do this.

I started wondering whether we should construct sets of sets, but this seemed to run into the same combinatorial explosion.

Comment: Is $k$ part of the input of K_ELEMENT, or is it fixed?

Comment: The problem K_ELEMENT can be solved in polynomial time, so you can given a polynomial time reduction which solves K_ELEMENT and then outputs either a fixed Yes instance of INTERSECT or a fixed No instance of INTERSECT.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus $k$ is part of the input.  If it weren't I think my first solution would become  a polynomial time reduction.

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the source?  Note that we require attribution for all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing